# StringIndexOutOfBounds Exception when trying to remove part of StringBuilder

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I`m trying to remove a subdirectory from a StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder mkPath = new StringBuilder("/sdcard/Downloads/mp3/mysong.mp3");

String nameToRemove = "/"+new File(mkPath.toString()).getName();

mkPath.delete(mkPath.lastIndexOf("/"),nameToRemove.length());
```

But it keeps throwing StringIndexOutOfBounds exception. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: is `StringBuilder b` supposed to be `StringBuilder mkPath`?

Comment: yes sorry is a mistake

Comment: you should be able to edit your question to fix the mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` because `mkPath.lastIndexOf("/")` is `21` and `nameToRemove.length()` is `11`.

Replace

```
mkPath.delete(mkPath.lastIndexOf("/"),nameToRemove.length());
```

with

```
mkPath.delete(mkPath.lastIndexOf("/"), mkPath.lastIndexOf("/") + nameToRemove.length());
```

because the `end` index must be greater than the `start` index.

Check [`StringBuilder.#delete(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#delete(int,%20int)) for more details on it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to manipulate file system paths is using `java.io.File` or `java.nio.file.Path`:

```
File parent = new File("/sdcard/Downloads/mp3/mysong.mp3").getParentFile();
```

or

```
Path parent = Path.of("/sdcard/Downloads/mp3/mysong.mp3").getParent();
```

Both return the path without "/mysong.mp3".

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve your goal more simply. You just want to remove everything from the last "/" to the end, right?

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder("/sdcard/Downloads/mp3/mysong.mp3");

b.delete(mkPath.lastIndexOf("/"),b.length());
```

As noted in the other answer, the second parameter to `delete()` is not the number of characters to delete, it is the last position to be deleted.  If you pass the length of the entire builder contents for this, it will delete to the end of the string.